Not able to boot compute module 4 via USB
I want to boot Raspberry PI 4 compute module. I am following documentation to setup Raspberry PI 4 with a Raspberry PI 64bit OS
I connected Micro USB slave port to linux host and connect J2 jumper to disable eMMC boot.
When I run sudo rpiboot, I am getting following error:

Failed to initialise libUSB

Note: I have checked libusb. It is properly installed.

I resolved this issue by building rpiboot from sources (https://github.com/raspberrypi/usbboot) instead of using 'sudo install rpiboot'
